# Custom initializer for custom UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionviewcell

I have a custom UICollectionViewCell that has a enum property that defines 2 types of cells. Let´s say one has an imageView and the other type has an UILabel. In both types there are other properties that are common to each other. In the cellForItemAtIndexPath: method I have:

```
CustomCollectionViewCell *cell = (CustomCollectionViewCell*)[self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.typeOfCell = enumCellType1; // or enumCellType2
```

and in the CustomCollectionViewCell initializer (initWithFrame:) what should I allocate? At this point I still don´t know what type of cell it is.

I use layoutSubviews to set the frame of all the common properties and at this point I know the typeOfCell value so I can set imageView or UILabel frames. But one of them must be allocated before in the initalizer.

If I had a custom initializer I could send the right type and set the property but that doesn´t work, I tried it.

Is it possible to create a custom initalizer or do I need to create 2 custom CollectionViewCells?

I´m not using any xibs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use inheritance?  Create a superclass that does all of the common set up and then two subclasses to do the specific setup.  You would then have two different reuse identifiers and allocate the right type of cell directly in `cellForItemAtIndexPath:`

Setting a cell 'type' is ignoring object oriented inheritance and will also cause you problems with re-use.

Comment: I agree. But is it possible to create a custom initializer?

Comment: I made a superclass cell with the common properties and 2 cells to define the type. I don´t know why a custom initializer didn´t work.